# How to access schema in a Kafka consumer when using schema registry?

Tags: node.js, typescript, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I'm integrating Kafka in our microservices architecture. We're using Karaspace as the schema registry, and protobuf as data format. So in producer microservice, there's a .proto file defined underlining the schema to be pushed and I've created corresponding **typescript** interfaces using [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-proto).

On the consumer side, schema registry will fetch the schema associated to the received data to validate and deserialise the data. But how do I access the corresponding interfaces in consuming microservice, so as to implement type checking?

Direct way seems to be writing interfaces for the expected response data beforehand. But then it will hamper schema evolution and I'll be back to square one.

Answer (score 1):

> writing interfaces for the expected response data beforehand

Yes, but you can also download them, not re-write. I.e. your producer code (assuming also Typescript) can be responsible for publishing the `.d.ts` types to common NPM registry, which the consumer adds as a dependency.

Or you can setup NPM/yarn pre-build hooks to download from the registry and run necessary `protoc` commands to compile the schema, similar to Confluent's own Registry Maven/Gradle plugins + Avro/Protobuf plugins.